# Create a clickable install script for software

Tags: apt, bash, software-installation, automation, scripts

I want to create a simple script that a user can download, click on, and it will:

1. request their root password through some sort of pop-up interface
2. then sudo apt-get install a package to their computer
3. and finally, run a few other commands to configure said software.

I know all the necessary bash in order to install and configure the software, my problem is in getting it to run with a single click.  (Sort of like a windows .exe installer).

How might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

With Windows `.exe`s you always have to at least double click. In ubuntu, there is no way to single click either, other than a `.deb`.

One of the ways Ubuntu is more secure is because it doesn;t let things run. To allow something to execute, you have to run the command `chmod +x file/to/be/executable` or right click, and change the permissions.

Because of this, there is no way to just double click and install.

Alternatives are to get the user to run the command themselves - `sudo apt-get install <package> && some-software-config-commands && another-config-command` etc.

You could also package it in a `.deb` file, the equivilent of a `.exe`